# How to get rid of values that doesnt meet threshold in pandas Dataframe (then plotting it)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I would like to know how can one plot only dots which are above some threshold in pandas scatter?
Lets assume I have dataframe like this - I had two datasets, I calculated difference between them (column "Difference"), then based on whether number in dataset1 was higher I gave it argument "True", if number in dataset2 was higher I gave it argument "False", finally there is atom number ("ATOM"):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'Difference': [1.095842, 1.295069, 1.021345, np.nan, 1.773725], 'ARG': [True, False, True, np.nan, False], 'ATOM': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    Difference  ARG ATOM
0   1.095842    True    1
1   1.295069    False   3
2   1.021345    True    5
3     NaN        NaN    7
4   1.773725    False   9
```

Then I plot the DataFrame to make scatter where the dots are colored based on whether is ARG True or False.

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
df.plot(x='ATOM', y='Difference', kind='scatter', color=df.ARG.map({True: 'orange', False: 'blue'}))
```

But what if I am only interested in plotting dots(ATOMS) which have "Difference" value above some threshold? E.g. difference >= 1.15?
Can I somehow drop all rows when in column "Difference" is value that doesnt meet required threshold?
I tried

```
df = df[df.Difference >= 0.15]
```

But it returns error: '>=' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'float'
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Try this `df = df[df['Difference']>=0.15]`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is slicing.

First you address the column you want to use as threshold (`df['Difference']`) and than slicing with a logical vector (`df[lg]`)

```py
lg = df['Difference'] >= 0.15 # logical vector
df = df[lg]
```

So in a minimum working example, you get:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# create dummy DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=['Col 1','Col 2','Col 4','Col 5'])
# thresholding
lg = df['Col 1'] >= 42
# slicing
df[lg]

len(df)
len(df[lg])
```

> `100`

> `56`